NO ME DEJA REPORTAR UNA PUBLICACION
buenas, disculpen mi redaccion esta es mi primera vez preguntando. Bueno a lo voy es que necesito encontrar la manera de poder reportar una publicacion en mi app, pero siempre me dice que hay error al reportar, ya que lo que necesito es que me borre la publicacion al llegar a cierta cantidad de reportes, ando usando kotlin y php.package com.example.prueba3.ivan.firsapp
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.example.prueba3.R
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.util.ArrayList

@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var linearLayoutPublicaciones: LinearLayout
    private lateinit var spinnerObjetos: Spinner
    private val listaObjetos = HashMap<String, String>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        linearLayoutPublicaciones = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPublicaciones)
        spinnerObjetos = findViewById(R.id.spinnerObjetos)

        obtenerObjetos() // Obtener objetos para poblar el Spinner

        // Configurar los botones para las actividades
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonPublicar).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, PublicarObj::class.java))
        }
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonPreguntar).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, PreguntarObj::class.java))
        }

        // Configuración de filtro por fecha
        val editTextFecha = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextFecha)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonFiltrarFecha).setOnClickListener {
            val fechaSeleccionada = editTextFecha.text.toString()
            if (fechaSeleccionada.isNotEmpty()) {
                cargarPreguntas(fechaSeleccionada, "")
                cargarObjetos(fechaSeleccionada, "")
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, selecciona una fecha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        // Configuración de filtro por tipo de objeto
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonFiltrarObjeto).setOnClickListener {
            val tipoObjetoSeleccionado = spinnerObjetos.selectedItem.toString()
            val idObjetoSeleccionado = obtenerIdDeObjetoSeleccionado(tipoObjetoSeleccionado)
            if (idObjetoSeleccionado.isNotEmpty()) {
                cargarPreguntas("", idObjetoSeleccionado)
                cargarObjetos("", idObjetoSeleccionado)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, selecciona un tipo de objeto válido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        // Cargar preguntas y objetos inicialmente
        cargarPreguntas("", "")
        cargarObjetos("", "")
    }

    // Función para obtener los objetos desde la base de datos
    private fun obtenerObjetos() {
        val url = "https://d358-187-190-223-141.ngrok-free.app/buscatec/obtenerObjetos.php"

        val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->
                try {
                    val listaTiposObjetos = ArrayList<String>()
                    listaTiposObjetos.add("Escoge un objeto")

                    for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                        val objeto = response.getJSONObject(i)
                        val idObj = objeto.getString("idObj")
                        val tipoObj = objeto.getString("tipoObj")
                        listaObjetos[idObj] = tipoObj
                        listaTiposObjetos.add(tipoObj)
                    }

                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listaTiposObjetos)
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    spinnerObjetos.adapter = adapter

                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al parsear los datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonArrayRequest)
    }

    // Función para obtener el ID del objeto seleccionado
    private fun obtenerIdDeObjetoSeleccionado(selectedTipoObj: String): String {
        for ((id, tipo) in listaObjetos) {
            if (tipo == selectedTipoObj) {
                return id
            }
        }
        return ""
    }

    // Función para cargar preguntas
    private fun cargarPreguntas(fecha: String, tipoObj: String) {
        val url = StringBuilder("https://d358-187-190-223-141.ngrok-free.app/buscatec/obtenerPreguntas.php?")
        if (fecha.isNotEmpty()) url.append("fecha=$fecha&")
        if (tipoObj.isNotEmpty()) url.append("tipoObj=$tipoObj")

        val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url.toString(), null,
            { response ->
                linearLayoutPublicaciones.removeAllViews()
                if (response.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No hay publicaciones para la fecha y tipo de objeto seleccionados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                        val pregunta = response.getJSONObject(i)
                        val titulo = pregunta.getString("tituloPregunta")
                        val descripcion = pregunta.getString("descripcion")
                        val fechaPublicacion = pregunta.getString("fechaPublicacion")
                        val tipoObj = pregunta.getString("tipoObj")

                        val contenedor = LinearLayout(this)
                        contenedor.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                        contenedor.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16)
                        contenedor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_relieve)

                        val textViewPregunta = TextView(this)
                        textViewPregunta.text = "$titulo\nDescripción: $descripcion\nFecha: $fechaPublicacion"
                        contenedor.addView(textViewPregunta)

                        val textViewTipoObjeto = TextView(this)
                        textViewTipoObjeto.text = "Tipo de objeto: $tipoObj"
                        contenedor.addView(textViewTipoObjeto)

                        linearLayoutPublicaciones.addView(contenedor)
                    }
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonArrayRequest)
    }

    // Función para cargar objetos
    private fun cargarObjetos(fecha: String, tipoObj: String) {
        val url = StringBuilder("https://d358-187-190-223-141.ngrok-free.app/buscatec/obtenerPublicaciones.php?")
        if (fecha.isNotEmpty()) url.append("fecha=$fecha&")
        if (tipoObj.isNotEmpty()) url.append("tipoObj=$tipoObj")

        val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url.toString(), null,
            { response ->

                if (response.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No hay publicaciones para la fecha y tipo de objeto seleccionados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                        val objeto = response.getJSONObject(i)
                        val titulo = objeto.getString("tituloPublicacion")
                        val modelo = objeto.getString("modeloObj")
                        val descripcion = objeto.getString("descripcionObj")
                        val fechaPublicacion = objeto.getString("fechaPublic")
                        val tipoObj = objeto.getString("tipoObj")
                        val imagenBase64 = objeto.optString("imagen", "")

                        val contenedor = LinearLayout(this)
                        contenedor.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
                        contenedor.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16)
                        contenedor.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.textview_relieve)

                        val textViewObjeto = TextView(this)
                        textViewObjeto.text = "$titulo\nModelo: $modelo\nDescripción: $descripcion\nFecha: $fechaPublicacion"
                        contenedor.addView(textViewObjeto)

                        val textViewTipoObjeto = TextView(this)
                        textViewTipoObjeto.text = "Tipo de objeto: $tipoObj"
                        contenedor.addView(textViewTipoObjeto)

                        if (imagenBase64.isNotEmpty()) {
                            val bitmap = base64ToBitmap(imagenBase64)
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                val imageView = ImageView(this)
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                                contenedor.addView(imageView)
                            }
                        }

                        // Dentro de la función que carga las publicaciones en HomeActivity:
                        val buttonReportar = Button(this)
                        buttonReportar.text = "Reportar"
                        contenedor.addView(buttonReportar)

                        buttonReportar.setOnClickListener {
                            // Obtener el idP de la publicación (esto debería estar disponible en el objeto de la publicación)
                            val idP = objeto.getString("idP")

                            // Enviar la solicitud para reportar la publicación
                            reportarPublicacion(idP)
                        }

                        linearLayoutPublicaciones.addView(contenedor)
                    }
                }
            },
            { error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            })

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonArrayRequest)
    }


    private fun reportarPublicacion(idP: String) {
        val url = "https://d358-187-190-223-141.ngrok-free.app/buscatec/reportarPublicacion.php"

        // Usar Map<String, String> para el parámetro
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params["idP"] = idP

        val jsonObjectRequest = @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, JSONObject(params as Map<*, *>?), // No es necesario el cast explícito a Map<Any?, Any?>
            Response.Listener { response ->
                val success = response.optBoolean("success")
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Publicación reportada exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // Recargar las publicaciones o eliminar la vista de esta publicación
                    cargarObjetos("", "")
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al reportar la publicación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                // Registrar el error en los logs para diagnóstico
                Log.e("ReportarPublicacionError", "Error al reportar la publicación: ${error.message}")

                // Mostrar un Toast con el mensaje del error
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        ) {}

        // Agregar la solicitud a la cola de solicitudes de Volley
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }




    // Método para convertir Base64 a Bitmap
    private fun base64ToBitmap(base64String: String): Bitmap? {
        if (base64String.isEmpty()) return null
        return try {
            val decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT)
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            null
        }
    }

}
Y aqui esta el php que segun yo nada mas tengo que usar para reportar la aplicacion:
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require_once 'conexion.php';

    // Obtener los datos del reporte
    $idP = isset($_POST['idP']) ? $_POST['idP'] : null;

    if ($idP) {
        // Incrementar el contador de reportes
        $query = "UPDATE publicarObjetos SET numReportes = numReportes + 1 WHERE idP = '" . $mysql->real_escape_string($idP) . "'";

        if ($mysql->query($query)) {
            // Verificar si el contador llegó al límite (3 en este caso)
            $result = $mysql->query("SELECT numReportes FROM publicarObjetos WHERE idP = '" . $mysql->real_escape_string($idP) . "'");
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            if ($row['numReportes'] >= 3) {
                // Eliminar la publicación si el contador de reportes es 3 o más
                $mysql->query("DELETE FROM publicarObjetos WHERE idP = '" . $mysql->real_escape_string($idP) . "'");
            }

            echo json_encode(["success" => true]);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(["success" => false, "message" => "Error al actualizar el contador de reportes."]);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["success" => false, "message" => "ID de publicación inválido."]);
    }

    $mysql->close();
}
?>
Y aqui esta mi tabla:
--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `publicarobjetos`
--

CREATE TABLE `publicarobjetos` (
  `idP` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tituloPublicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `noControl` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `modeloObj` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descripcionObj` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fechaPublic` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `idForaneoObjetos` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `imagen` longblob NOT NULL,
  `numReportes` int(5) DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

 --`introducir el código aquí`
 -- Volcado de datos para la tabla `publicarobjetos` 
 --

Y pues es todo hasta ahorita no se la verdad porque no me deja realizar el reporte. En si lo que busco es que a la hora de darle click al boton reportar el campo numReportes se incremente en 1 y asi cuando llegue a un limite, que en mi caso le puse 3, pues la publicacion que llego a 3 se elimine

El típico error de novato. Mostrar un mensaje que diga "Ha ocurrido un error" y NO MOSTRAR EL ERROR REAL no ayuda en absoluto. Eso es un error para el usuario, que no necesita conocer detalles de la implementación ni datos concretos del error. Pero TU, como PROGRAMADOR, NECESITAS saber exactamente qué está pasando. Cómo podemos ayudarte si no vemos más que el mensajito bonito que pones tú mismo?? Al menos añade debajo de tu toast un log que puedas ver en la consola de android studio!! Y luego usa el enlace [edit] y pon aquí el error exacto que tienes. Si no, es imposible ayudarte
